# Autowiring for @Service field failed

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I keep looking at my codes all day along, I can't find the cause. The repository (@Repository) is working just fine, it's the *@Service* field that I keep failing get it autowired, I keep struggling since everything looks fine

[image]

The dispatched servlet:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<context:component-scan base-package="com" />
```

**com.repository**

***Repo.java***

```
package com.repository;
import com.domain.Student;
import java.util.List;

public interface Repo { public List<Student> getAllSiswa();  }
```

***RepoImplement.java***

```
import com.domain.Student;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public class RepoImplement implements Repo {
 List<Student> ls = new ArrayList<>();

public RepoImplement(){  
        Student s1 = new Student();
        s1.setNama("paul");

        Student s2 = new Student();
        s2.setNama("robert");

        ls.add(s1);
        ls.add(s2);
}

    @Override
    public List<Student> getAllSiswa() {    
       return this.ls;
    }
}
```

**package com.service;**

***Serve.java***

```
import com.domain.Student;
import java.util.List;

public interface Serve {
    void changeName(String namaBaru);
    public List<Student> newList();
}
```

I'm suspecting there's something wrong over here

***ServeImplement.java***

```
import com.domain.Student;
import com.repository.Repo;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class ServeImplement implements Serve {
    @Autowired
    public Repo repo;  
    List<Student> s = repo.getAllSiswa(); // THIS IS SUSPECTING ME.

    @Override
    public void changeName(String namaBaru) {
        s.get(0).setNama(namaBaru); // get first Student, then update its name.
      }
    @Override
    public List<Student> newList() {
        return this.s;
    }
}
```

***controller2.java*** (*it's the mapping request for serving student*)

```
package com.controlller;
import com.domain.Student;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import com.service.Serve;

@Controller
public class controller2 {

    @Autowired
    public Serve serv;

    @RequestMapping("/changename")
    public ModelAndView sdaf() {
        serv.changeName("New name");
        List<Student> list = serv.newList();
        return new ModelAndView("page2", "out", list);
    }
}
```

The error:

> Error creating bean with name 'controller2': Injection of autowired
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: public com.service.Serve
>   com.controlller.controller2.serv; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'serveImplement' defined in file
>   [C:\Users\hans\Documents\NetBeansProjects\WebApplication2\build\web\WEB-INF\classes\com\service\ServeImplement.class]:
>   Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not
>   instantiate bean class [com.service.ServeImplement]: Constructor threw
>   exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Ya. `repo` could be `null`. Do you see a NPE in the stacktrace?

Comment: @VinodMadyalkar, thanks for the response, yes it's null pointing on `List<Student> s = repo.getAllSiswa();`, but I can't find why, since it looks that it gets wired correctly..

Comment: Put `repo.getAllSiswa();` in a method marked as `@PostConstruct`

Comment: @VinodMadyalkar, in the `RepoImplement` right after `@Override` ??

Comment: No. In `ServeImplement` :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to understand how autowiring, or in fact Java in general, works.

Spring must create an instance of your ServImpl class, and populate the field `repo` with the repository bean. It does that using reflection, but what it does is basically equivalent to the following code:

```
ServImpl s = new ServImpl();
s.repo = theRepoBean;
```

So, you see that `s.repo` becomes non-null **after** the constructor has been executed. And, while executing the constructor, the following line of code is executed:

```
List<Student> s = repo.getAllSiswa();
```

At that moment, `repo` hasn't been initialized yet. So it's null. So you get a NullPointerException.

Use constructor injection instead of field injection, or use a `@PostConstruct` annotated method.

And please, make your fields private instead of public.

That said, the goal of a repository is normally to get data from a database. And the students can be modified,deleted or created in the database. So initializing a field of your service and returning always the same list defeats the whole point of having a repo. You should call `repo.getAllSiswa()` from newList(), every time it's called, to get the latest, up-to-date, list of students.

Comment: Yes this is what came to my mind for a second.., but let me first try it out.

Comment: I'm sorry if it's funny question, but the `Student` is initialized in the `RepoImplement` constructor then `@Autowired public Repo repo;` there,  won't be null. Or I'm missing something..

Comment: You seem to be missing all my answer. Read it again. What is null is the repo field in the service. It has nothing to do with students.

Comment: @AngryDumbassSlapper - See, when the construction of `ServImpl` is happening, `repo` is not initialized and hence will be null. You are calling a method on it, so you get NPE.

Comment: Yes it's working now, I put *@Autowired* above the constructor.and initialized the List inside it .. thank you so much...guys (and @VinodMadyalkar thanks bro..)

Answer (score 1):

Because `Autowired` on field happens right after construction, you need to change your code in order to get it to work.

This should works:

```
@Service
public class ServeImplement implements Serve {

    public Repo repo;
    List<Student> s;

    @Autowired
    public ServeImplement(Repo repo) {
        this.repo = repo;
        s = repo.getAllSiswa();
    }

    @Override
    public void changeName(String namaBaru) {
        s.get(0).setNama(namaBaru); // get first Student, then update its name.
    }

    @Override
    public List<Student> newList() {
        return this.s;
    }

}
```

Moreover, using `Autorwired` annotation on constructor allow you to mark your field as `final` if the instance shouldn't have to change.

Comment: Thank you @Fabian.., yes solution works (it's the concrete implemention of JBNized answer)..