# Null pointer for field injection

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm missing fundamental things here that I do, I'm sorry for this question, basically I tried to simulate my own question from [Autowring for @Sevice field failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34491116/autowring-for-sevice-field-failed) , but in very simple form , I tried to somehow raise errors on purpose for building understanding, but when it comes, I just can't handle it.

x-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns= ...... >
   <context:component-scan base-package="com" /> 
     <context:annotation-config />
    <bean  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />   
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**com.domain**

Boss.java

```
package com.domain;
public class Boss {
    private String name;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Employee:

```
package com.domain;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
public class Employee {
    @Autowired
    private Boss boss;
     String nameBoss;

    public String getNameBoss() {
       nameBoss = this.boss.getName();
       return nameBoss;
    }

}
```

**com.controller**

```
controller.java :

package com.controller
import com.domain.Boss;
import com.domain.Employee;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;


@Controller
public class controller {    
    @RequestMapping("/try")
    public String show() { 
        Boss b = new Boss();
        b.setName(" hans");

         Employee e =  new Employee();  
          String bossName = e.getNameBoss();            
        System.out.println(bossName );      

    return "";
}
 }
```

I was thinking that,

```
String bossName = e.getNameBoss();
```

in controller won't be null because *Boss* is already initialized right before *Employee* construction, but I'm wrong ..

Comment: the boss object has no relation with the employee object. They are just two separate objects. If you are referring the `@autowire` magic then this is not how it's supposed to work. `@autowire` will inject the dependency from the dependencies specified in the context file.

Comment: You have a few issues here. An IoC container like Spring will manage some objects for you and, if it does, you can't instantiate them yourself. If you want to autowire an object, it has to be an object the container manages, which means you have to annotate it with something like @Service. If it is something the container manages, then you should not be instantiating it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the response guys, when in spring core, I tried to also simulate this, the only difference that , I could load the beans from ApplicationContext#getBean, but in Spr. MVC, how I load the bean for those  *Employee* & *Boss* ..,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my Spring @Autowired field null?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896870/why-is-my-spring-autowired-field-null)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you want to have dependency injection (DI) for domain objects? This is not a typicall usage... For a DI, container have to create instances - so do not use `new` operator...

You can replace new operator using `ApplicationContext.getBean()` (iff the bean is of type prototype), but as I said above - even if you know how to create such beans, how should Spring know, which instance of `Boss` you want to have in Employee?

First thing you need is application context in controller, which should work to add interface `org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware` or you can simply [autowire it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4914012/how-to-inject-applicationcontext-itself) and then use it "standard" way (ac is ApplicationContext):

```
    Boss b = ac.getBean(Boss.class);
    Employee e = ac.getBean(Employee.class, b);
```

I have `Boss` and `Employee` marked with annotations as:

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class Boss {

...

}

@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class Employee {

    // @Autowire - wrong
    Boss boss;

    public Employee(Boss boss) {
        this.boss = boss;
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: I think that the only way to get rid of the `new` operator, is by loading the beans from the context of Spring, Like in spring core we use `ApplicationContext#getBean` , but if only I know how to load those `Employee` & `Boss`.. then I think I could get rid of those `new` operators

Comment: Thanks for your edit, the implementor class for  *ApplicationContext* that I usually used is `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(`...`);`, but it has argument which is a path to the context configuration, if i try `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(`/WEB-INF/x-servlet.xml/`)` then it won't work.., help me bro..

Comment: Do have to first declare both `Boss` & `Employee`, with `<bean...>`, in `x-servlet.xml`??

Comment: No, you do not need to, you have component scan, so use `Component` and `Scope` annotations...

Comment: That means I have to create custom config. for the beans, for now I'll upvote you, let me understand first.

Comment: pretty much stuff in my head right now.. :D, I feel guilty that I won't bother you futher, like *Boss b = ac.getBean(Boss.class);* how do I set property for the b` (`b.setName` ?), also there `Boss b = ac.getBean(Boss.class);` seems like *invisible* new., which means the same :D, but just wait for tommorow, I'll learn it first.., thank you

Comment: Exactly - `b.setName`, you have your instance, so do what you need to do with it... As I said at the beginning, typically it's not used with domain objects - there is not added value doing so...